# Creating Relationships using Azure AD external identities

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 Azure AD tenants one tenant using B2C and a main tenant that has my application running. The tenant uses Azure AD to authenticate the users. I want the users in my B2C tenant to be able to access my web application without having to add them in my main tenant. Is this something that is possible within Azure? Could we use Azure AD external identities and create a relationship between the 2 tenants?

Comment: Just to re-clarify, so you want B2C as Identity provider in the AAD, right? Not the opposite? For the later scenario (which is common), I recently answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63722634/13791953)

Comment: I want my users in my B2C tenant to able to access my application in my main tenant without having to add them as a guest user in my main tenant.

Comment: Which, to me, is another way of saying "I want my application to allow users from B2C". Unless you are ready to do little bit of code/configuration change in the actual application (I mean your web application), it's not possible otherwise. Your app should be updated to integrate with B2C user flow and application to achieve that. I mean B2C should be your primary IDP for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such settings/tool with which we can use 1 directory  along with another directory.

To achieve this goal, you will have to write the code yourself. For example, you can write a service which pull the users from the Azure AD B2C and adds them to Azure AD using [Azure AD Graph.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#performing-rest-operations-on-users)

Comment: I don't really want users to be added as guests in my main directory. So this solution wouldn't really work. I'm guessing Azure doesn't really have the feature for this yet.

Comment: What type of users are they?