# Blazor Wasm .Net 5 - Implement both Individual User Accounts and Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

Below Microsoft documentation explains how to protect a Blazor WASM Hosted app using two different authentication approach.

[1. Individual User JWT Authorization(IdentityServer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[2. Azure AD Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

There is a need to provide end-user with both options by combining both authentication mechanism in a single app. The user should be able to choose one of the options from the login page.

The Azure AD option is just to give end-users to SSO experience and besides that, all authorization logic will be handled locally using individual user accounts.

Once the user is authenticated using the Azure Adoption, there should be a way to link the user with a local ID to handle authorization logic etc.

I did a lot of online research but I couldn't find a guide or tutorial to implement this. I tried to implement this by combining the code but I'm stuck with:

1. Enabling both Local/AzureAd login option in Blazor client login page
2. Linking the Azure AD user with the local user in the server

**Blazor Client Code**

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorWasmIndvAuth.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorWasmIndvAuth.ServerAPI"));


        //OPTION 1
        //Azure Ad Authentication
        builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://123456/Api.Access");
        });

        //OPTION 2
        //Individual User JWT authentication
        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that your client application and API's prefers to only have to deal with one authorization server. Supporting multiple will be pretty messy.

My proposal is that your applications only deal with IdentityServer, but allow to login To Azure AD (Federated authentication) through IdentityServer. See the ExternalController.cs file in the QuickStartUI in IdentityServer.

See this [page](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/users/)

Comment: I like the 'IdentityServer' only approach. Unfortunately, I can not find an example of how to configure a Blazor WASM Client app to cater to both local & AzureAD authentication. Some reference will be really helpful.

Comment: try https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/ui/login/external/

Comment: Your Blazor app you configure to only accept IdentityServer login. Then in IdentityServer you add support for external AzureAD authentication. The Blazor app will not be aware of Azure AD